# Strict ANSI C - 8 bit struct elements a violation?

Tags: c

I have defined a struct as follows:

```
struct Display7
{
    U8 a : 1;
    U8 b : 1;
    U8 c : 1;
    U8 d : 1;
    U8 e : 1;
    U8 f : 1;
    U8 g : 1;
}Display7;
```

If I disable Strict ANSI C check in Keil IDE, there is no errors.
If enable Strict ANSI C, I get the error "non standard type for a bit field".
What is causing the problem?
If I make each struct element as U32,then ANSI C doesn't complain.

Comment: What is the exact definition of `U8`?

Comment: Why not using uint8_t?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala; The fact is even `_Bool` takes 8-bit.

Comment: @haccks - at least 8 bit. :) It might be even larger. I initially thought I knew compilers where it is larger than 8 bits, but could not find any.

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that using bit-fields in general is a bad idea. Particularly if standard compliance and portability are desired.

Comment: U8->uint_8= unsigned char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard is clear about it:

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**: 5/ A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified
>   version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other
>   implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether
>   atomic types are permitted.

Comment: Haha, we answered at the same time. I like both answers. Yours is very very precise, I'd like to think mine is very succinct. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: so a type of unsigned char,unsigned short int is not permitted?Only unsigned int/signed int/_Bool is permitted?

Comment: That's it. You can be sure to be able to use these types, any other may be forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Bit fields with a type other than signed or unsigned `int`, or `_Bool`, is optional in C99.

Comment: Haha that was recursive :)